# can anyone solve these system of equations from the picture?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

[image]

I tried to solve this system by eliminating variables and use augmented matrix to solve, I am still working on it so if you could solve it, please shed me some light. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$x_1+x_2=8$$
$$x_3-x_4=6$$
$$x_1+x_3=13$$
$$x_2+x_4=8,$$

which you can write as 
$$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1}\pmatrix{x_1 \\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}=\pmatrix{8 \\6\\13\\8}.$$

Can you take it from here?

The solution is

> $$\pmatrix{x_1 \\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}=\frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{7 \\9\\19\\7}$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the system:

$$\begin{cases}I&x+y=8\\
II&z-w=6\\
III&x+z=13\\
IV&y+w=8\end{cases}$$

Observe that

$$II+IV: z+y=14\;,\;\;I-III:\;-z+y=-5$$

and solving the above two equations, first adding and then substituting:

$$2y=9\implies y=\frac92\;,\;\;z=14-\frac92=\frac{19}2$$

and then, with I and II

$$x=8-\frac92=....etc.$$